# Crash on Deserialize on blob data in c++

Tags: c++, crash, deserialization, blob

The Application is crashed while deserializing the one of the complex structure called S. The definition of the structure will be changed during the course of time .

This complex structure is stored as blob in database. on retrieval we will deserialize. The crash happens at this moment.

Reason :
During the software development over the time, we will add some new members or some other sturcutes to the existing structure s. This will be incompatible for deserializing.

we can check for service version , that alone wont be solved. we have to check for framework version also. If all are compatible then we will deserialize.

**Is there any better solution "To store the complex data as blob and deserialize it safely, even though the definition of the structure changed" ?**

Comment: Regarding "any better solution", use versioned serialization? Do you use a third-party library for the serialization, or have you created your own? Using e..g [Boost serialization](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html) will make it easy to serialize (and deserialize) complex structures which might change and be added to.

Comment: Thx for the quick response. I am using the interface, which is provided by framework. Is there any chance to avoid versioning ? Is there any alternate to store complex data into a database  instead of blob ?